# update dict in list comprehension

Tags: python, dictionary, list-comprehension

Given the two dictionaries below, I'm trying to create a list of new dictionaries combining the items from one (com), which will repeat for each member, with only the values of the second (e), entered one at a time, under key 'n'. E.g. first list member would be:
`{'n': 330, 'b': 2, 'a': 1}`
If I use update() within the list comprehension to add the key-pair values from the first dictionary to the result I get a list with two None members.
I've tried different ways to write this, e.g. using map() and on both python 2 and 3; so I ask the experts.

```
>>> com
{'b': 2, 'a': 1}
>>> e
{'p': 330, 'r': 220}
>>> [n for rt in e.values() for n in [{'n':rt}]]
[{'n': 330}, {'n': 220}]
>>> [n.update(com) for rt in e.values() for n in [{'n':rt}]]
[None, None]
```

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking.

Comment: As @AKS points out your question is not clear. Also, unless you are trying to create an obfuscated Python contest submission a list comprehension is frequently not the appropriate tool. An explicit for loop may be easier to understand. As shown by the answer by Martin. I love Python and its "comprehensions" syntax but find the insistence by many programmers to distill every loop into a single line comprehension incomprehensible.

Comment: Disagree. It's pretty clear they're asking how to use a comprehension to update `dict` types inline. They even put a comprehension in a code sample and mentioned the `dict.update()` operation which [returns `NoneType` instead of a reference to the updated `dict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.update).

Answer (score -1):

To clarify the problem statement:

> Given a fixed map `com` and a map containing a series of elements (I would find the name 'nvals' more mnemonic), return a list of maps, where each element of the list has one of the values from `nvals` as the value of key `'n'`, and all the elements of `com`.

So the following code returns the required result:

```
>>> com = {'b': 2, 'a': 1}
>>> nvals = {'p': 330, 'r': 220}
>>> l = []
>>> for n in nvals.values():
...     d = dict(com) # Make sure to clone the dictionary.
...     d["n"] = n
...     l.append(d)
...
>>> l
[{'n': 330, 'b': 2, 'a': 1}, {'n': 220, 'b': 2, 'a': 1}]
>>>
```

The trouble is that is not a list comprehension

```
>>> [dict(list(com.items()) + [('n', n)]) for n in nvals.values()]
[{'n': 330, 'b': 2, 'a': 1}, {'n': 220, 'b': 2, 'a': 1}]
>>>
```

Seems to meet the requirements.

I have to say, I think I find the loop easier to read.

Comment: Note:  I am sure your variable names are mnemonic in the context of the wider program - but for *this problem*, I think mine are better.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
    com = {'b': 2, 'a': 1}
    e = {'p': 330, 'r': 220}
    res = [{i:j for i,j in com.items()+[("n",v)]} for v in e.values()]
```

Or this:

```
    res = map(lambda x: dict([("n",x)]+com.items()), e.values())
```

Or maybe:

```
    res = [dict(zip(["n"]+com.keys(),[v]+com.values())) for v in e.values()]
```

Don't you just love python?

Answer (score -1):

You can use a comprehension for this by persuading Python to execute the `.update()` method from `dict` in a conditional:

```
[n for rt in e.values() for n in [{'n': rt}] if n.update(com) or True]
```

Here a conditional is added as an execution scaffold for the stateless `.update()` operation which always returns `None`. (NoneType is equivalent to `False`.) To ensure the flow control always executes the conditional is set `True` with an `or` statement.

Alternately, a collection object can be created from `.update()` (always `None`) to ensure `True` so that it always executes:

```
[n for rt in e.values() for n in [{'n': rt}] if (n.update(com),)]
```

Note that the `(None,)` is a tuple of length 1 that evaluates to `True`.

Comment: Not exactly the most Pythonic but it gets the job done. If there's another way to do this in a comprehension, feel free to let us know.